# How can I interpret quaternion orientation into compass heading angles?

Tags: trigonometry, quaternions

I am using a BNO055 sensor to generate quaternion orientation data. My goal is to calculate accurate compass heading angles from quaternion orientation data.

Interpreting compass headings using Euler angles is a trivial task, however it is susceptible to Gimbal Lock, which is why the sensor I am currently using is pushing out quaternion orientation data.

However, my question is how can we interpret quaternion orientation data into compass headings? All of the methods I have seen online require converting quaternion orientation data into euler angles and from there converting the "roll", "pitch", and "yaw" of the euler angles into compass heading angles.

I want to avoid this and only use quaternion orientation data, however I'm not sure how to interpret:

```
x, y, z, w
```

into compass heading angles?

Is there no way to avoid converting quaternion orientation data to euler angles before I can get my desired compass heading angle?

I know that:

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
w = 1
```

would be displayed as `North` on a compass. However, how do I move on from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quaternion $q$, I assume, give a rotation from some reference vector $v$. So all we have to do is rotate $v$ with $q$. Represent $v$ as an imaginary quaternion. Then it rotates $v$ via $qvq^{-1}$ where $q^{-1} = \bar q/(q\bar q)$ with $\bar q$ the conjugate. Note that if $q$ is normalized properly then $q^{-1} = \bar q$; I will assume this. The quantity $qvq^{-1}$ can now be interpreted as a vector describing your heading.

Since you say $x = y = z = 0$ and $w = 1$ correspond to north, then $v$ is the north-pointing vector. Let's say $v = (1,0,0)$. Then we represent this as an imaginary quaternion $v = i$; if $q = w + xi + yj + zk$ then
$$\begin{aligned}
  qv\bar q
  &= (w + xi + yj + zk)i(w - xi - yj - zk)
\\
  &= (wi - x - yk + zj)(w - xi - yj - zk)
\\
  &= wx - xw - yz + zy + (w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2)i + (wz + xy + yx + zw)j + (-wy + xz - yw + zx)k
\\
  &= (w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2)i + (wz + xy + yx + zw)j + (-wy + xz - yw + zx)k.
\end{aligned}$$
So if $(0,1,0)$ is east, corresponding to $j$, then angle $\theta$ from north to east is given by
$$
  \tan\theta = \frac{w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2}{wz + xy + yx + zw}.
$$

Comment: The angle you would get from taking the inverse of the tan() would be between ```-90deg``` to ```+90deg```. The compass heading angles range between ```0deg``` to ```360deg```. Would a sensible solution be to add the resulting angle by ```90deg``` and multiplying it by ```2```?

Comment: @AngoMango No. Let $x$ be the $i$ component and $y$ the $j$ component above so that we have $\tan\theta = x/y$. When $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$ then $\arctan x/y$ will give the correct angle. When $x\geq0$ and $y<0$ you need $180^\circ-\arctan x/y$. When $x<0$ and $y<0$ you need $180^\circ+\arctan x/y$. And when $x<0$ and $y\geq0$ you need $360^\circ + \arctan x/y$.

Comment: So, I was able to get it to output some interesting heading values with your calculations. At ```0deg```, it seems to output the True North heading with an error of ```2deg``` to ```6deg```, which I believe does get the actual True North Heading.

 However, it looks like there is a limitation in the angle range that the compass provides. That is, angles jump from ```90deg``` to ```270deg``` - there is no in between. Any reason why this may happen?

I do convert the result of the inverse of the ```tan()``` before I subtract, or add it, to those angles you provided.

Comment: The other strange thing is that the calculation you provided does give me the True North value at ```0deg```, but the resulting ```x```, ```y```, ```z```, and ```w``` values are ```-.01```, ```-.01```, ```.71```, and ```.71```. That may be as close as I can get to ```0```, ```0```, ```0```, and ```1```.

Comment: @AngoMango I may have made some mistakes, and I also can't do anything about the physical reality of your measuring device. It would be better practice to use a quaternion multiplication function than to hardcode the result in terms of components. You should also make sure the $j$ direction is east as that was an assumption I made.

Comment: You should also check my transformations of $\arctan$; what might be better is programming languages usually have an $\mathrm{arctan2}$ function, and with this we only need two cases: if $x\geq0$ then we need $\mathrm{arctan2}(x, y)$, and if $x<0$ we need $360^\circ+\mathrm{arctan2}(x,y)$.

Comment: The arctan2() method did the trick. I'll need to do a bit more research on the trigonometry behind IMU data. I'll mark yours as the solution, however this snippet: ```f x≥0 then we need arctan2(x,y), and if x<0 we need 360∘+arctan2(x,y).``` resolved it. Thank you.